# I have got "Primefces is not defined" in Cypress, even if manually works everything properly

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am automating test with Cypress, when I click on the button which leads me to another normal page (normal means no pop ups, no anything special) I got this error: "Primefces is not defined ... at filedownload.js?ln=prime". How should I overcome this issue?
Thank you so much.

When("Some step in BDD story (in someFile.feature)", () => {
cy.contains(`Some button`).click()
})
It should click on it and take me to another page within the same web app

Instead I got "Primefces is not defined ... at filedownload.js?ln=prime"